# Finding Coordinates on a Bufferred Image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

I have a buffered image of a 4x4 checker Board (resolution 400x400) rendered on half a JPanel. Is it possible to find the coordinates of each square corner without doing it manually? I'm using absolute positioning on the JPanel and it is the only container besides the Frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 4 x 4 checkerboard that's 400 x 400, then each square is 100 x 100 pixels.

When you construct a `BufferedImage` like this, you save a `Rectangle` for each square as you're doing the construction.

That way, when you do a mouse click later, you can use the `contains` method of `Rectangle` to determine which square was clicked.

You shouldn't use absolute positioning.  If your checker board takes up half the JPanel, `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout` works well.

Comment: Well, they are not perfect squares(forgot to mention) and the squares are not independent but altogether in an image. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: @Anon855: Sure.  Put the image in Microsoft Paint or some other paint program and count the pixels.  Create a Rectangle for each square.  Your other alternative is to write a class that draws a checker board by constructing a BufferedImage.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for an example that is ..something vaguely like what @GilbertLeBlanc is suggesting.